# Duplicating BP Sky Sphere in UE5

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

When I duplicate BP_Sky_Sphere, it gives the same reference to the original blueprint so that I cannot make changes to it. How do I make a copy so that it does not change the original blueprint?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Blueprint that derives from it. When creating a Blueprint, choose BP_Sky_Sphere as the Parent Class by typing the name in the search bar.

[image: Creating a Blueprint]